# Compare string against array and extract array elements present in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following string:

```
str = "This is a string"
```

What I want to do is compare it with this array:

```
a = ["this", "is", "something"]
```

The result should be an array with `"this"` and `"is"` because both are present in the array *and* in the given string. `"something"` is not present in the string so it shouldn't appear. How can I do this?

Comment: What if a word occurs multiple times? In the string: `s = "foo foo"; a = ["foo"]` or in the array: `s = "foo"; a = ["foo", "foo"]` (or in both)

Comment: BTW, `"this"` and `"This"` are different strings.

Comment: Why not show us what you've tried, and we'll help correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
str = "This is a string"
a = ["this","is","something"]
str.downcase.split & a
# => ["this", "is"]
```

I am assuming Array `a` will always have keys(elements) in downcase.

Comment: does this change the array "a"?

Answer (score 1):

There's always many ways to do this sort of thing

```
str = "this is the example string"
words_to_compare = ["dogs", "ducks", "seagulls", "the"]

words_to_compare.select{|word| word =~ Regexp.union(str.split) }
#=> ["the"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) smell to it. Usually when we want to find what words exist the next thing we want to know is how many times they exist. Frequency counts are all over the internet and Stack Overflow. This is a minor modification to such a thing:

```
str = "This is a string"
a = ["this", "is", "something"]

a_hash = a.each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i] = 0 } # => {"this"=>0, "is"=>0, "something"=>0}
```

That defined `a_hash` with the keys being the words to be counted.

```
str.downcase.split.each{ |k| a_hash[k] += 1 if a_hash.key?(k) }
a_hash # => {"this"=>1, "is"=>1, "something"=>0}
```

`a_hash` now contains the counts of the word occurrences. `if a_hash.key?(k)` is the main difference we'd see compared to a regular word-count as it's only allowing word-counts to occur for the words in `a`.

```
a_hash.keys.select{ |k| a_hash[k] > 0 } # => ["this", "is"]
```

It's easy to find the words that were in common because the counter is > 0.

This is a very common problem in text processing so it's good knowing how it works and how to bend it to your will.